# Can I slave a MACVTAP interface to a bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, virtual-network

Initial evidence suggests no:

```
$ sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
$ sudo ip link add macvtap0 link eth0 type macvtap
$ sudo ip link set macvtap0 master br0
RNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macvtap interfaces directly connect the lower device (in this case eth0) with the 'tap' consumer (qemu) – and because they redirect all packets sideways to the 'tap' consumer, nothing gets forwarded "up" to the host OS network stack where a bridge could see them (which would need a 3-way split), which means they can have neither a L3 IP address nor a L2 master device.

But the whole reason macvtap interfaces work this way is to *avoid* the need to use bridges. So if you want to use a bridge anyway, then you should be able to **use a regular `tap` interface** instead of macvtap.

Comment: I don't think macvtap is what I'm after but I can't think how to do it.  I'm trying to create an SSH L2 tunnel (ie `-o Tunnel=ethernet` and get the remote-end tap bridged to an Ethernet port.  Thing is, I don't have any access to the remote except by SSH and SSH goes over the Ethernet port.  If I get it wrong, I get to drive several hours to sort it out.  So I wanted to bridge a macvtap to the tap adapter that SSH creates, giving me a very low-risk way over extending the L2 domain over SSH.  But it seems it can't be done.

Comment: I've also tried creating a macvtap adapter called `tap1` and telling SSH to use it as its tap adapter but this, sadly, doesn't work.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need a macvlan, not macvtap.

Answer (score 0):

You can add mactvtap device to the bridge and add eth0 to the same bridge.

```
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
sudo ip link add macvtap0 link br0 type macvtap mode bridge
sudo ip link set macvtap0 master br0
```

Now you can you ebtables :)
You can use other modes of macvtap device like "vepa".

Comment: Are both "link br0" and "master br0" really necessary? As in, if "link br0" adds macvtap0 to the br0 bridge, wouldn't "master br0" be superfluous?